# Why does vertical-align: middle push my image out of its container?

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/aT458/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="va-m">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <h1> vertical-align: middle </h1>
</div>
<div id="no-va">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <h1> no vertical align </h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;

    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#va-m img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

h1 {
    display: inline;
}

img {
    border-radius: 75px;
}
```

I'm trying to align the image and text vertically in the container div. However, I seem to either get the choice of aligning the image, or aligning the text. Using vertical-align: middle on the img tag pushes it out of the container. Why?

Comment: http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the height to `auto`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aT458/4/)

```
div {
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 5px;    
    width: 500px;
    //height: 150px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Update: Use `table` and `table-cell` + `vertical-align: middle`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aT458/6/)

Comment: This somewhat works, however the text is not perfectly vertical aligned (it becomes obvious if you change the h1 font-size to 4em - the bottom is aligned, not the center of the text). Is this possible to fix?

Comment: @Rotten194 - Kindly check updated fiddle if that's what you want.

Comment: It fixes the image problem, but not the text alignment one. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aT458/7/) for an exaggerated example. The bottom of the 'V' should be below the bottom of the 150x150 text in the image, but it's at the same level instead.

Comment: @Rotten194 That is because the container has `fixed` width and the text is quite big.  I change it to 100% or auto - http://jsfiddle.net/aT458/8/

Comment: Hm... that didn't seem to fix it on my actual site. Whatever, I ended up just replacing the image + logo text with a single image. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Rotten194 No problem. I forgot to mention that I remove the `line-height` as well. Just in case you haven't remove it and still causes problem.